# CSS border radius background colour bleed

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with weird bleed/artifacts around a border radius when I have an element inside.

I have searched through a lot of posts about similar problems and the only recommendations I've seen, that seem to work for others, aren't working for me. Recommendations like:

```
div {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle to replicate the problem. Look at the top left and right corners and you can see some of the parent's black background showing through.
https://jsfiddle.net/2596n440/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Chrome, this issue is reported [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491574).

I suspect the cause is the same across browsers: the elements are being cropped separately and the anti-aliasing allows bleed.

The fix would be on a case by case basis with the goal of removing the shared perimeter. For your example, it would be matter of rearranging the elements such that they are a top and bottom rather than a parent and child. If that's not an option, you might be able to go with adjusting the CSS a bit:

```
.outer {
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 456px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -228px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: black;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/ /* removed */
    z-index: 150;
    position: fixed;
}
.inner {
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0; /* added */
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top:-1px; /* added */
 }
```