# White borders display when setting border radius

Tags: reactjs, html, css

I'm working with the [react material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) framework and when I try to set `border-radius` for the background `<div>` of the circle `svg` a narrow white border is displayed in Chrome.

Does any one know How I can hide this white border and make the stroke edge smooth and sharp?

I set this css code:

```css
svg {
  border-radius: '50px';
  background-color: white;
}
```

and here is the sample code that I work on:
[Code Pen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYVPZm)

[image: border around circle]

Comment: I don't have experience with SVG, but have you looked at the `stroke` property for broders instead? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke/

Comment: Actually that is not the problem with `stroke-with` trying different numbers for this property does not change anything. I think this mostly relates to how browser is rendering border-radius. Not even `svg` is an issue in this problem

Comment: can u provide your svg code

Comment: It's hard to tell, if we could only see the issue on an image and not in life code.

Comment: in code pen you can see the white borders on the top left side

Comment: Known issue with Chrome as I recall and sub-pixel rendering/anti-aliasing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174981/css-border-radius-background-colour-bleed

Comment: Can you show your markup too so we can see how you're embedding the SVG? I assume the `background-color` is just to color the checkmark, correct? If so why not just change the `fill-color` of that path in the SVG?

Comment: If you can modify the SVG another easy trick is to make the background shape (blue part) a square and then let CSS round the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```css
svg {
  shape-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}
```