# Overflow hidden does not fully hide parent div with border radius

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am getting some residual overflow from my simple layout below. Though minimal, the effect is quite obvious and happens only where I set a border radius. The expected behavior is to have the `div class='inner'`, the white, fully cover `div class='outer'`, the red. However there clearly seems to be residual overflows from both ends of the div.

**Example:**

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5rem;
}
.inner {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I am using this as part of a loading bar effect where `inner` translates as part of an animation during a media play. I have read a couple other problems that involve adding properties like `z-index` and adding `masks` but does not work for me. Also read issues with `webkit`, but have not found anything that works in the case above.

**Edit**

For clearer illustration refer below:-
Overflow hidden is being used so that when inner translates, any overflow is hidden out of the parent div. I am unsure if there are any other ways I can use. Below is an example of having the x-axis translate at 10%. I am trying to achieve the overflow effect without any bleeding from the edges around where border radius is applied.

Translate starts at 0% which is the same as the example above.

This issue was also reported - [Issue 491574: border-radius bleeds background-color](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491574)

And similar to the question - [CSS border radius background colour bleed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174981/css-border-radius-background-colour-bleed) but the use case of overflow does not apply to my case.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The code above though not in exact flavor is embedded in an app written in ReactJS and I am facing this issue both in Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, could you add an image of your desired result to make it clearer?

Comment: @koder613 OP is making a progress bar using the inner div as the progress indicator. As you see if you run the code, the background color of the `outer` div can be seen on the left and right because of the border-radius. OP wants the `inner` div to cover that or the background color not to "bleed".

Comment: I should add when I'm back on PC - but I expect it to be fully white as per the inner div.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS border radius background colour bleed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174981/css-border-radius-background-colour-bleed)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I edited my question to show clearer my use case and that answer might not be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I suggested as a duplicate mentions:

> The fix would be on a case by case basis... it would be matter of rearranging the elements such that they are a top and bottom rather than a parent and child.

So here is your case fix. You have to have the background red color into a child of the container element... And the progressbar on top of it. Now that the container doesn't have any background color, nothing can bleed due to the anti-aliasing.

Additionnally, if you apply the same `border-radius` to the "background" div... And a 1px white border... The magic is made.

Below, I animated the `width` of the `.progress-bar` on an interval to simulate you react state based animation.

```js
// Simulating an animation... Just for this demo.

let outer = document.querySelector(".outer")
let progress = document.querySelector(".progress-bar")
let outerWidth = outer.getBoundingClientRect().width
let progressWidth = progress.getBoundingClientRect().width

let interval = setInterval(function(){
  progressWidth = progress.getBoundingClientRect().width
  progress.style.width = progressWidth + 10 + "px"
  if(progressWidth > outerWidth) clearInterval(interval)
},500)
```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress-background {
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);  /* to compensate the white border space */
  height: calc(100% - 2px); /* to compensate the white border space */
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5rem;      /* Same radius than the container */
  border: 1px solid white;  /* white border */
}
.progress-bar {
  background: white;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: width 1s;  /* Just to have the animation a bit smooter */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="progress-background"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely blurs the effect, but if you change the green to white, you can see bleeding still happens.

Comment: I finally found the real fix.... It is about a white border for the background div.... ;)

Comment: Ahh well, thanks for the taking the time. Just so frustrating that it does not work as intended because of the anti-aliasing.

Comment: Yes I agree! And for at least more than 5 years! lol!