# why there has a 1px gap between border-radius parent container and hover child element

Tags: html, css

when parent has background-color and border-radius css, there has a 1px gap between hover child. How to let hover child complete cover the parent container.

example Code :

```css
.parent{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}
.child1, .child2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.parent:hover .hover-child{
  display: block;
}
.hover-child{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="hover-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS border radius background colour bleed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174981/css-border-radius-background-colour-bleed)

Comment: It's probably not a 1(CSS)pixwl gap, but a sort of 'left behind' set of screen pixels. The system has to work out how to map CSS pixels into screen pixels - on modern high res screens there is more than one screen pixel per CSS pixel and there can be a sort of rounding error effect when it's trying to decide how to deal with part pixels.

Comment: How to resolve this problem in css

Answer (score 0):

```css
.child {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.parent{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the trouble child is a hover element in my project, it must use absolute position